# PHP working with files inside an archive

Tags: php, file, archive

Is there a PHP supported way to work with an archive of files (.zip, .tar or any other archive) same way we work with a folders?

For example if in our root "/www/" directory there is an archive "/www/catalog.zip" that contains .php files, would it be possible to include this archive with PHP so that PHP would know what is inside the archive and if required to include a file (for example test.php that is inside the catalog.zip) we can do so without extracting the "catalog.zip" archive?

Not sure if something like this exists (of course it would be possible to build a application to do something like this, but it would be resource if done with PHP using extract read/remove)

or maybe there is something similar that can be used?

Comment: There is no way for any application to work with the data of any archived file without extracting it. That's sort of the point of an archive. This is not entirely true for uncompressed archives like `tar`, but in finding the correct start and end points in the archive to read from, you are effectively extracting the file.

Comment: I understand that Dave, but if something like that is possible then maintaining and working with files (especially uploading) would be easier, imagine working with large project with over 1000 files or even with a ckeditor (the amount of files it has (even if it is only around 5mb) takes about 30min to upload with a slow connection) :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like `ZipArchive::getStream` together with `stream_get_contents` would get you the file content but I'm not sure how you'd include it - don't think php can `include` from stdin

Comment: In that example, you wouldn't `include` it but `eval()` (evil) it. But you wouldn't do it anyway, you'd just store the files in a directory and not bother to archive them.